# How to solve for $x$ by minimizing infinity norm: $\arg \min_{x} \left\{\|y - Ax\|_{\infty}\right\}$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

$y$ and $x$ are vectors and $A$ is a $m$ x $n$ matrix such that $n$ > $m$

Comment: minimization is taken with respect to which variable ?

Comment: sorry that i didnt mention this before. But I want to solve for x.

Answer (score 2):

You can transfer this into a linear optimization problem:
$$
\min t
$$
subject to 
$$
-t \le y_i - (Ax)_i \le t.
$$
Then solve this problem using a standard method (e.g., simplex method).

Comment: I still dont know how to solve this problem. Could you please help me with it?